# How to populate the alt tag in lightbox 2

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using lightbox 2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) on a site and I don't see an alt tag in the images that are open? It is a requirement from the client.

Is there anywhere I can populate the alt tag ? The lightbox image is opened like so

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
```

How would I pass an alt tag to the lightbox ?

Comment: what is the output you need ?

Comment: just to have the <img> tag of the lightbox populated with some alt text. When the lightbox is running, inspecting the element there is no alt tag for each of the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript attach the alt tag afterwards, something like:

```
$("light_box_img").attr("alt", $("original_img").attr("alt"));
```

I can help with a more detailed solution, but will need you to post some code...